# PHP getopt with if() elseif() break the middle condition

Tags: php, getopt

I am not sure what is going wrong, nor from the official documentation I can get much help.

But this is what is happening.

I have option 'a', 'c:' and 'm:' to read from the command line using `getOpt()`

They are laid out as:

```
if ($op = getopt("a")) {

    doAll();

} elseif ($op = getopt("c:")) {

    doSome($op["c"]);

} elseif ($op = getopt("m:")) {

    doOne($op["m"]);

} else {

    echo "INVALID ARGS"; exit;

}
```

The option 'a' and 'm' works find but when I use option 'c' with:

`php4 rebuild_mastertag.php -c 1234`

It always prints `INVALID ARGS`

To make things more mysterious if I pass 1 or 12 or 12345678 it works but it doesn't for 123, 1234, 12345, 123456, 1234567 sort of numbers.

Really baffled.

Thank you for for your time.

Comment: Think about using an IDE, Like Netbeans or anything similar. They use to highlight the coding errors (or possible errors) like  unintentionals assignments in conditions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the assignment is intended and he does not want to compare the values. Nevertheless, it's right that this shouldn't be done within the if-statement and I'd recommend using only one assignment like `$op = getopt("ac:m:")` or similar.

Comment: Yes, hchr, the assignment is intentional for shorthand.

Comment: Is this the complete code? If I try it myself, the c-part gets executed (doesn't matter if I pass '-c 1234' or '-c 1').

Comment: It is complete upto now, I am trying to see if it calls the right routine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @hchr

Your solution seems to work without trouble:

`$op = getopt("ac:m:");`

`if (empty($op)) {
    alertForInvalidArgument();
} else {
    callProcessor($op);

}`

```
function callProcessor($op)
{
    if ($op["a"]) {

        doAll();

    } elseif ($op["c"]) {

        doSome($op["c"]);

    } else {

        doOne($op["m"]);

    }
}
```